# Netty - Call a method on connection termination

Tags: java, sockets, io, netty, nio

I've been trying to figure out how to go about calling a method when the connection has been forcefully terminated by the client, or if the client just loses connection in general. Currently I have an List<> of all of my online accounts, however if the player doesn't log out of the server naturally, the account will stay in the list.

I've been looking through the documents, and searching google wording my question in dozens of different ways, but I can't find the answer that I'm looking for.

Basically, I need a way to figure out which channel was disconnected, and pass it as a parameter to a method, is this possible? It almost has to be.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this can be done using thread on both client and server side.

Make a Date variable lastActive in client class which will be set by client every 5min (let's say). Another thread will run from server side every 10 min to check for this flag, if lastActive is more than 10min then remove player from list. You can change this frequency time according to your need

Comment: I thought about doing this, but it would be ridiculously inaccurate, what if the player disconnected one minute after the 10-minute check during a multiplayer raid, then he couldn't log back in for another 9 minutes, because his "Account is already logged in."? That doesn't sound very efficient. When the connection is forcefully closed there is an Exception that's thrown, but I can't figure out which exception it is, (I guess I'm not throwing it anymore, but I used to)

Answer (score 0):

Reliably detecting socket disconnects is a common problem and not unique to Netty.  The issue as you described is that your peer may not reliably terminate their end of the connection.  For example: peer loses power, peer application crashes, peer machine crashes, etc... One common solution is to close the connection if no read activity has been detected for longer than some time interval.  Netty provides some utilities to ease this process such as the [ReadTimeoutHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html).  Setting the time interval is application specific and will depend on your protocol.  If your desired interval is sufficiently small you may have to add additional messages to your protocol to serve as a heartbeat message (a simple request/response to indicate each side is talking to each other).

From a Netty specific point of view you can register a listener with the Channel's [CloseFuture](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#closeFuture()) that will notify you when the channel is closed.  If you setup the ReadTimeoutHandler as previously described then you will be notified of close events after your timeout interval passes and no activity is detected or the channel is closed normally.

Comment: @Christian.tucker - Any thoughts or questions?  Is this not the answer you were looking for?